# MATLAB Avoid text overlap in a map

Tags: matlab, dictionary, plot, overlap, points

I have a map that's plotting points with labels. Now, in places where the labels are close together, the labels overlap. I saw that some people suggested textbp (FileExchange), but I'm getting my labels from a column in a cell array so that function doesn't work. How can I make it so labels are placed far enough from the point for all labels to be seen clearly? Maybe add arrows if it's not clear which label is for which plot?

The data is this file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/li3hh1nvt11vok5/4YGfwStQlo. 
I pulled out data from this file and sorted it, found unique values, and then used that to plot the points.

Here's the map part of my script:

```
%% Use function to read in 2012
    % Format: data = ('filename', 'delimiter')
filename = ('PM2.5_NY_2012.csv'); % PM2.5 88101 and 88502 data from NY 

data = read_mixed_csv(filename,', '); % 2012 must have ',' taken out first. DO NOT need to use for 2011 
data = read_mixed_csv(filename,'"'); % Creates cell array of data (2011, 2012)
data = regexprep(data, '^"|"$',''); % Gets rid of double quotes at the start and end of the string 
data = data(:,2:2:end); % 2012. Do it only if there are blank columns. Keep only the even cells because the odd ones are just commas
PM25_NY_2012 = data;

%% Pull data of a specific parameter (Latitude and Longitude - Columns 20 and 21)

% Pull out data with Local Conditions only (Locations differ compared to Acceptable PM2.5
data_Loc = data(strcmp('PM2.5 - Local Conditions', data(:,10)),:);

% Pull out data with Acceptable PM2.5 AQI only
data_Acc = data(strcmp('Acceptable PM2.5 AQI & Speciation Mass', data(:,10)),:); 

%% Find index for the first unique lat and lon
% Local Conditions
[C,ia,ic] = unique(data_Loc(:,2));
DupIndex = setdiff(1:size(data_Loc(:,2)), ia);
data_Loc(DupIndex,:) = [];

datalat_Loc = data_Loc(:,19);
datalon_Loc = data_Loc(:,20);

% Acceptable PM2.5
[C, ia,ic] = unique(data_Acc(:,2));
DupIndex = setdiff(1:size(data_Acc(:,2)), ia);
data_Acc(DupIndex,:) = [];

datalat_Acc = data_Acc(:,19);
datalon_Acc = data_Acc(:,20);

%% Plot map
latlim = [39 47];
lonlim = [-81 -70];
figure('Color','w');

% Plot for Acceptable PM2.5
subplot(1,2,1)

usamap('New York'); % 'Vermont', 'Massachusetts', 'Rhode Island', 'Connecticut', 'New Jersey', 'Pennsylvania', 'Delaware', 'Maryland')
shi = shaperead('usastatehi', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
            'Selector',{@(name) strcmpi(name,'New York'), 'Name'});
geoshow(shi, 'FaceColor', [0.3 1.0, 0.675])
textm(shi.LabelLat, shi.LabelLon, shi.Name, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center')

[row,col] = size(datalat_Acc);
nb_point = row;
LAT = str2double(datalat_Acc);
LON = str2double(datalon_Acc);
h = geoshow(LAT, LON, 'DisplayType', 'Point', 'Marker', '*', 'Color', 'red');
textm(LAT, LON,(data_Acc(:,2))', 'FontSize',8)
title('PM2.5 Sites in New York State in 2012 - Acceptable PM2.5 AQI & Speciation Mass');

hold all

% Plot for Local Conditions
subplot(1,2,2)

% figure('Color','w');
usamap('New York'); % 'Vermont', 'Massachusetts', 'Rhode Island', 'Connecticut', 'New Jersey', 'Pennsylvania', 'Delaware', 'Maryland')
shi = shaperead('usastatehi', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
            'Selector',{@(name) strcmpi(name,'New York'), 'Name'});
geoshow(shi, 'FaceColor', [0.3 1.0, 0.675])
textm(shi.LabelLat, shi.LabelLon, shi.Name, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center')

[row,col] = size(datalat_Loc);
nb_point = row;
LAT = str2double(datalat_Loc);
LON = str2double(datalon_Loc);
h = geoshow(LAT, LON, 'DisplayType', 'Point', 'Marker', '+', 'Color', 'red');
textm(LAT, LON,(data_Loc(:,2))', 'FontSize',5)
title('PM2.5 Sites in New York State in 2012 - Local Conditions');
```

So the issue is with the `textm` part of the script that plots the labels in a way that overlaps.

[image: Here are the two subplots. As you can see, the parts where there are a lot of points are a mass of black]

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't run as is, hangs up without datalat_Acc. I don't know if that was in one of those files or not. However, you could solve this issue by iterating through as you make the text labels and dynamically altering their position. Write out the first label, get the position of that label, and set the position of the second label to be slightly below it. Then you get the position of that second label, and use it to adjust the third, and so on. You can also use those positions to draw a line between the label and the map point. In this example, I have them all pointing at the same place, but you can change that if you adapt this for your code.

```
clf
hold on
plot(peaks)
h=text(5,8,'label1', 'FontSize',8);
posh=get(h,'position');

for i=1:5
    h2=text(posh(1),posh(2)-0.5,['label',num2str(i+1)], 'FontSize',8);
    posh=get(h2,'position');

    plot([posh(1) 0],[posh(2) 7])
end
```

I am sure there is a way to do this without iterating through all of them, but this is what came to mind as easiest to write.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to do what you suggested. I'm pretty new to coding in general. I've updated my script above to include the missing parts. It should run now. Can you take a look? It would help me figure it out to have something that pertains more to my particular case.

Comment: Well it still won't run without read_mixed_csv(). But you should still be able to adapt my example. The get(h,'position') function returns an array [x-coordinate y-coordinate z-coordinate] of the text label. So you are using LAT and LON values in the textm() function instead of x and y. So first you need to change your textm(LAT,LON...) function into a for-loop, then you can work on replacing LAT and LON with position(1 & 2). In the loop, each time you place a textm() label, you can use a lat value of lat(i)=lat(i-1)-#degrees, which will move the label down #degrees below the previous label.

Comment: I will try doing that and hopefully, will be able to get it working. I've added read_mixed_csv to the folder. It was written by someone who posted it as an answer to a Stackoverflow question so I forgot about it.

Comment: Hey. I tried the code on my script and it looks like what your code runs by itself. But it doesn't point to each point and tell me what the title is. Instead, it gives me a column of the labels. Do you know what I am doing wrong? I want each label to be pointed to. Currently, I can't tell which point is which label. Thanks.
I added the following where `textm` was before. I only changed the first subplot for now

Comment: `h = textm(LAT(1,1), LON(1,1),(data_Acc(1,2))', 'FontSize', 8);
posh = get(h, 'position');

for i = 1:length(data_Acc)
    h2 = text(posh(i), posh(i+1)-0.5, [(data_Acc(:,2))',num2str(i+1)], 'FontSize',8);
    posh=get(h2,'position');

    plot([posh(1) 0],[posh(2) 7])
end`
The code has also been saved into the folder.

Comment: I'm thinking it's not working correctly because I'm only finding the position of the first dot or something. Is that the problem? How do I fix it?